# Change language IVR

Tags: php, xml, ivr, vxml

I developed an IVR in VXML with `<prompt>` in French text, then I duplicated and translated to make it available in English and Spanish but I can't change the pronunciation despite the language tag.

(My Spanish text is read by a French voice, so incomprehensible)

Here's my current header:

```
<? xml version="1.0" ?>
<vxml version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" xml:lang="fr-FR">
```

Has anyone already succeeded?

Comment: is it not related to the xml:lang? I don't have the tools to try it, but does this example come out with two pronunciations? https://github.com/voximal/voicexml-examples/blob/master/helloworld/helloworld3.vxml

Comment: yes I tried full of possibilities (es, es-ES, es-MX, en-GB, en ....) but my text translated in English or Spanish is read by a French voice, without accents

Comment: You may wish to try the xml:lang attribute as part of the prompt, as per the VoiceXML specification section 4.1. You may also wish to to verify that your platform supports Spanish TTS.

Answer (score 0):

What language packs are installed ?
If the value of xml:lang is not among the available localizations , your TTS fallback will be read in the default language regardless of how the text is written .

Can you share more details , application or voice browser logs ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Voximal, the latest versions have a promptlanguage property that allows to gloabl force the language for the TTS.

Another option to use multi language support with prompts is to use the method:

```
    <prompt cond="lang=='fr'" xml:lang="fr-FR"><value expr="welcome"/></prompt>
    <prompt cond="lang=='en'" xml:lang="en-UK"><value expr="welcome"/></prompt>
    <prompt cond="lang=='es'" xml:lang="es-ES"><value expr="welcome"/></prompt>
```